# Google OAuth2 - Exchange Access Code For Token - not working

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, oauth2-playground, youtube-analytics

I am currently in the process of implementing a server-side OAuth2 flow in order to authorize my application.

The JS application will be displaying YouTube Analytics data on behalf of a registered CMS account to an end user (who own's a channel partnered with the CMS account). As a result of this, the authorization stage needs to be completely hidden from the user. I am attempting to authorize once, then use the 'permanent' authorization code to retrieve access tokens as and when they're needed.

I am able to successfully authorize, and retrieve an access code. The problem begins when i attempt to exchange the access code for a token.

The HTTP POST Request to achieve this needs to look like this...

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

I am using this code to achieve this:

```
var myPOSTRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();



myPOSTRequest.open('POST', 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', true);
myPOSTRequest.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
myPOSTRequest.send('code=' + myAuthCode + '&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FCMSAuth3.html&client_id=626544306690-kn5m3vu0dcgb17au6m6pmr4giluf1cle.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=&client_secret={my_client_secret}&grant_type=authorization_code');
```

I can successfully get a 200 OK response to this Request however no access token is returned, and myPOSTRequest.responseText returns an empty string.

I have played with Google's OAuth Playground - and can successfully get a token using my own credentials.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: It looks like in your code, you are using "authorization code" as your grant type.

Comment: Hi Emily, my apologies i had pasted the wrong example - edited with accurate example using grant_type=authorization_code

Comment: Paste the actual http requests and responses. Compare these with the equivalents from Oauth Playground

Comment: @pinoyyid The OAuth playground seems to obscure the actual requests by doing them on the server side

Comment: @Michael the request and response are displayed on the web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this, because there is the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). This is a security concept of modern browsers, which prevents javascript to get responses from another origin, than your site. This is an important concept, because it gives you the ability, to protect you against [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). So don't use the code authorization flow, use instead the [token authorization flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent).

Comment: I realised this in the end, so i now have a PHP file that retrieves that access token, and saves it to a .txt file for use in the client-side application. My problem now is in trying to load the API's now that i have this access token. I have tried using XMLHttpRequest()'s, but run into the same cross-origin issue (despite the google documentation stating this is the CORS friendly way to do it)

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure, because I didn't try, but maybe Google distinguishes between access tokens, that are retrieved with authorization flow and token flow. Try using Fiddler and look up, if Google sends a header like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Answer (score 1):

Try and build up the full URL.  Then dump it in a webbrowser.  If its corect you will get the json back.  You have the corect format.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code=<myAuthCode>&redirect_uri=<FromGoogleAPIS>&client_id=<clientID>&client_secret={my_client_secret}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Other things to check:

1. Make sure that you are using the same redirect_uri that is set up in google apis.
2. How are you getting the Authcode back?  If you are riping it from the title of the page i have had issues with it not returning the full authcode in the title try checking the body of the page.  This doesnt happen all the time.  I just ocationally.

Comment: I always get this exception. Any clue why?

{
error: "invalid_request"
error_description: "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}

Comment: Is this a GET or a POST request?

Comment: @PuneetPandey  It's a POST request, have you tried the server [side implementation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server). It works for me